Is there a function where we can consider working days if I work only 10 hours a day between 8am - 6pm
Sample Data
Working hours between 8am -6pm
=(NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2)-1)*("18:00:00"-"8:00:00")+IF(NETWORKDAYS(C2,C2),MEDIAN(MOD(C2,1),"18:00:00","8:00:00"),"18:00:00")-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2)*MOD(B2,1),"18:00:00","8:00:00")
our working hours are between 8am -6pm weekdays, we do not work on weekends. The task can arrive any time in the system, we pick it up and work on it only between our working hours. The above is the formula I used to extract only the hours worked (8am -6pm) to complete the Task.
My question is, if I am working only 10 hours in a day, then this formula is giving me the hours:minutes:seconds properly when customized as [h]:mm:ss.
If I customize the format d:hh:mm:ss, I get 1 day 23 hours 54 minutes 43 seconds.
My requirement is 4 days 7 hours 54 minutes 47 seconds.
I am struggling to figure out the formula.
Time Spent column includes the total time including weekends. Its raw data




Task ID
Arrival Date
Departure Date
Time spent
days:hours:minutes:second
Working Hours between 8am-6p Time 8-6 in decimal format
Time 8-6 in decimal format




1-2QPM
01/14/2022 19:18:25
01/14/2022 19:18:25
Days:0 Hours:0 Minutes:0 Seconds:0
0 :0 :0 :0
0:00:00
0


1-2QPM
01/14/2022 19:18:25
01/14/2022 20:20:06
Days:0 Hours:l Minutes:l Seconds:41
0 : 1 : 1 : 41
0:00:00
0


1-2QPM
01/14/2022 20:20:06
01/21/2022 15:54:47
Days:6 Hours:19 Minutes:34 Seconds:4
6 : 19 : 34 : 41
47:54:47
1.996377315


1-2QPM
01/21/2022 15:54:47
01/21/2022 16:21:24
Days:0 Hours:0 Minutes:26 Seconds:37
0 : 0 : 26 : 37
0:26:37
0.018483796


1-2QPM
01/21/2022 16:21:24
01/21/2022 17:25:28
Days:0 Hours:l Minutes:4 Seconds:4
0 : 1: 4: 4
1:04:04
0.044490741




The difference is because your "day" is only ten hours, and the formatting is based on a 24 hour day. So while you get the correct number of hours, you have to do some mathematical transformations to convert that to 10 hour days

I agree with the comment that you can make some arithmetic conversion on the result of the formula to get Days + Hours.
Another approach would be to breakdown the formula directly:
The first part of formula =NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2)-1 calculates working days, while the second part =IF(NETWORKDAYS(C2,C2),MEDIAN(MOD(C2,1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2)*MOD(B2,1),upper,lower) handles the working hours in start date and end date if they are not holidays.
So basically, you can just use first part to calculate days, and the second part to calculate remaining working hours.
The second part, =IF(NETWORKDAYS(C2,C2),MEDIAN(MOD(C2,1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2)*MOD(B2,1),upper,lower) will always result in a number that lies in the range of [-10 Hours, 10 Hours] (lower boundary = lower-upper, upper boundary =upper-lower). when this part is a negative number, you need make some adjustment.
In below table, column D uses =NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2)-1, column E uses =IF(NETWORKDAYS(C2,C2),MEDIAN(MOD(C2,1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2)*MOD(B2,1),upper,lower)
In row4, you can see columnE is negative, that means you need to subtract one day from columnD to get "Full Working Days", and add 10hours to columnE to get the remaining working hours.
The second table displays the formula I use.




Task ID
Arrival Date
Departure Date
Working Days
Stub Hours in decimal format
Full Working Days
Stub Hours




1-2QPM
44575.8044560185
44575.8044560185
=NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2)-1
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(C2,C2),MEDIAN(MOD(C2,1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2)*MOD(B2,1),upper,lower)
=IF(E2>=0,D2,D2-1)
=IF(E2>=0, E2,(upper-lower)+E2)


1-2QPM
44575.8044560185
44575.8472916667
=NETWORKDAYS(B3,C3)-1
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(C3,C3),MEDIAN(MOD(C3,1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B3,B3)*MOD(B3,1),upper,lower)
=IF(E3>=0,D3,D3-1)
=IF(E3>=0, E3,(upper-lower)+E3)


1-2QPM
44575.8472916667
44582.6630439815
=NETWORKDAYS(B4,C4)-1
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(C4,C4),MEDIAN(MOD(C4,1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B4,B4)*MOD(B4,1),upper,lower)
=IF(E4>=0,D4,D4-1)
=IF(E4>=0, E4,(upper-lower)+E4)


1-2QPM
44582.6630439815
44582.6815277778
=NETWORKDAYS(B5,C5)-1
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(C5,C5),MEDIAN(MOD(C5,1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B5,B5)*MOD(B5,1),upper,lower)
=IF(E5>=0,D5,D5-1)
=IF(E5>=0, E5,(upper-lower)+E5)


1-2QPM
44582.6815277778
44582.7260185185
=NETWORKDAYS(B6,C6)-1
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(C6,C6),MEDIAN(MOD(C6,1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B6,B6)*MOD(B6,1),upper,lower)
=IF(E6>=0,D6,D6-1)
=IF(E6>=0, E6,(upper-lower)+E6)




The following formula give the result seen in the screenshot.
In the example calculation is shown step-by-step, the partial results can be replaced in the final cell, or include them in a LET function.
J58: =INT(HOUR(H57)/10)+MOD(HOUR(H57),10)/24    convert hours from 10hours/day to 24 hours/day
K58: =INT(DAY(H57)*24/10)+MOD(DAY(H57)*24;10)/24 convert days count to 10hours/day and further again 24hours/day
L58: =J57+K57+MINUTE(H57)/1440+SECOND(H57)/86400 add partial results to display. The cell custom format dd:hh:mm:ss


A limitation of this method is that dd can only display accurately values in the range 0-31. So if he might have a duration >31 days, he will need a different method.
